# Ubuntu 20.04: Compile and run C# program accessing PostgreSQL using Npgsql

Tags: c#, postgresql, mono, npgsql, ubuntu-20.04

This is my first time trying to get a C# program to work on Linux. I wrote a script installing all the dependencies and one compiling and executing the program.

I installed the following dependencies:

```
sudo apt install mono-complete -y
sudo apt install libnpgsql2.2-cil -y
sudo apt install nuget -y
nuget update -self
nuget install Npgsql
```

My compilation and run script looks like this:

```
mcs -out:bin/FillDatabase.exe FillDatabase/Version_2/FillDatabase.cs
mono bin/FillDatabase.exe
```

My problem is that I am getting the following error message:

```
error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Npgsql' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
```

Npgsql.dll definitely exists. I even copied it to the source code and tried:

```
mcs -out:bin/FillDatabase.exe FillDatabase/Version_2/FillDatabase.cs /reference:FillDatabase/Version_2/Npgsql.dll
```

That causes the following new error:

```
error CS0012: The type `System.ICloneable' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. Consider adding a reference to assembly `System.Runtime, Version=4.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
```

So I next tried:

```
mcs -out:bin/FillDatabase.exe FillDatabase/Version_2/FillDatabase.cs /reference:FillDatabase/Version_2/System.Runtime.dll /reference:FillDatabase/Version_2/Npgsql.dll
```

However, the same error message returns.

**Update 0:**
The program compiles perfectly using Visual Studio 2019 on Windows 10.

**Update 1:**
Solved by using .NETCore.

Comment: Why are you using Mono and not .NET Core?

Comment: Try to make sure the current directory is bin, and that it directly contains all required files. So you don't have to care about the path to your binary files

Comment: Can you share your csproj file?

Comment: I am trying .NETCore.

Comment: I second Ian's question. With Core becoming .NET 5 in the near future, it makes more sense to have new developments use  that for linux support.

Comment: It works with .NETCore. Sorry for having caused the trouble. I have completely forgotten that .NETCore supports Linux and that Mono is obsolete.  As a matter of fact, the Windows Version does use .NETCore 3.1. Like I said, I usually do not program in C# for Linux.